# Spring MVC Static Resource Sometimes Can't Find

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

First, Sorry about my poor english

=================================

My static resource in '/resource/images/test1/image1.png'

When "test1" folder is exist

I can call '127.0.0.1:8080/myproject/resource/test1/image1.png' find it

if i call '127.0.0.1:8080/myproject/resource/test1/image1.png' when folder not exist yet

of course i can't find it

but even i call url when after dynamically create folder

i still can't got image

EX1:

Call url before create folder and call again after dynamically create folder

------ **Can't find, Only Get 404 Not Found**

EX2:

Create folder before call url and call again

------ **Can find**

I thought it was a cache problem at first

But when EX1 problem occur, stall occur even change browser

Both EX are deployment on linux

I have the following Setting

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">  
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/base-config.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>120</session-timeout>
  </session-config>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>signin</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 ........
 ........
 ........
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan
    base-package="com.chat.controller" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/resource/**" location="/resource/" cache-period="0"/>   


<!-- jsp views -->
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're using old-style XML configuration instead of Spring Boot?

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- I inherited this project from my company seniors

Comment: Ah, it appeared this was for a new project. This is often caused when the source resources aren't copied into the `target` or other build directory; it may be necessary to run `mvn compile` or tell your IDE to rebuild the project. One of the problems with war projects is also that they can get stuck on outdated versions; in some cases you might need to rebuild and restart. Start by checking your output directory while your app is running to make sure your new file is copied there.

Comment: problem occur only when deployment on linux , if run on the IDE it will not happen, i can't rebuild it when run on linux, this features must be dynamically create folder, Sorry about my poor english again

Comment: Then it's certainly because there are several steps involved (source->target, target->deployment, sometimes more) and those are not all getting executed.

Comment: but in the EX2, i can find the resource image, even create folder after deployment